# « En [cette] soirée », « dans la soirée », « hier au soir», cette soirée-là »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Ici il est question d’un message tiré d’une conversation [imaginaire] qui raconte un fragment de soirée entre amis qui a eu lieu la journée précédente.

Tu hésitais beaucoup devant l’alternative qui s’offrait à toi, d’un côté tu voulais que ton prétendant nous rejoigne chez toi car il semblait très sérieux dans les messages qu’il t’envoyait, mais d’un autre côté tu étais très fatigué **en [cette] soirée.**

Tu hésitais beaucoup devant l’alternative qui s’offrait à toi, ou faire venir ton soupirant et rester éveillé encore longtemps, ou ne pas le faire venir et dormir. D’un côté tu voulais que ton prétendant nous rejoigne chez toi, d’autant qu’il semblait très sérieux dans les messages qu’il t’envoyait mais d’un autre côté tu étais très fatigué **dans la soirée**.

Tu hésitais beaucoup devant l’alternative qui s’offrait à toi, ou faire venir ton soupirant et rester éveillé encore longtemps, ou ne pas le faire venir et dormir. D’un côté tu voulais que ton prétendant nous rejoigne chez toi, d’autant qu’il semblait très sérieux dans les messages qu’il t’envoyait mais d’un autre côté tu étais très fatigué **hier au soir**.

Tu hésitais beaucoup devant l’alternative qui s’offrait à toi, ou faire venir ton soupirant et rester éveillé encore longtemps, ou ne pas le faire venir et dormir. D’un côté tu voulais que ton prétendant nous rejoigne chez toi, d’autant qu’il semblait très sérieux dans les messages qu’il t’envoyait mais d’un autre côté tu étais très fatigué **à cet instant-là**/**à ce moment-là.**

Devrais-je plutôt écrire « au moment où vous vous écriviez »; je tiens absolument à insérer une référence temporelle, mais si vous pensez qu’elle est inutile, n’hésitez pas à m’indiquer cette information.

————

Ton prétendant souhaitait te voir, il voulait de son propre chef faire la longue route jusque chez toi, plus de 150 kilomètres séparant vos demeures, tout laissait supposer qu’il était très sérieux, je t’encourageais même à accepter la proposition, mais toi, en cette soirée/ dans la soirée/ à ce moment-là/ à cet instant-là, tu étais très fatigué.

- Tout en répondant à la question, vous pouvez aussi repenser la phrase entièrement.

Comment: "tu étais très fatigué ce soir-là" n'y était pas. [attention: cela n'est pas une phrase. C'est un commentaire.]

Comment: @Lambie Merci 

Comment: Est-ce que vous croyez que je me torture l’esprit inutilement avec cette question? Sachez qu’il m’est de plus en plus difficile de mettre mes pensées en mots et mon neurologue m’a rien décelé d’anormal: c’est comme si mon esprit se désagrégeait lentement de jour en jour sans laisser de trace physique…

Comment: Peut-être il ne s'agit pas d'un mal physique, mais d'un mal psychique....

Comment: Ton prétendant souhaitait te voir, il voulait faire 150 kilomètres jusque chez toi, tout laissait supposer sa détermination, je t’encourageais même à accepter, mais pour toi, ce n'était pas le moment. [moins c'est verbeux, mieux la tête se porte … on peut aller jusqu'à la la contraction de texte]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En alexandrins :

*Loger le postulant ou céder à Morphée

Je te vois hésitant en cet après-souper*

Comment: @Pogo … mieux que la contraction de texte maximale des textes de loi où il n'y a plus rien à retrancher — « *Tout condamné à mort aura la tête tranchée* » —, l'expression poétique rimée …  ou pas …  laisse passer les instants et émotions indicibles.